# C ternary expression-statement not working

Tags: c, conditional-statements

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int a=3,b=4,g;
  a > b ? g = a : g = b ;
  printf("%d",g);
  return 0;
}
```

Why does the value of `g` not get printed? And compiler says `lvalue` required. What does it mean?

Comment: You've to change `a > b ? g = a : g = b ;` to `g = a > b ? a : b;` or `a > b ? g =a : (g = b);`

Answer (score 15):

Due to higher precedence of operator `?:` over `=`, the expression

```
a > b ? g = a : g = b;
```

will be parsed as

```
(a > b ? g = a : g) = b;
```

The expression `(a > b ? g = a : g)` will give an rvalue. The left operand of assignment (`=`) operator must be an lvalue<sup>**1**</sup> (modifiable<sup>**2**</sup>).

Change

```
a > b ? g = a : g = b ;
```

to

```
a > b ? (g = a) : (g = b);
```

or

```
g = a > b ? a : b;
```

---

<sub>**1**. C11-§6.5.16/2: *An assignment operator shall have a modifiable lvalue as its left operand.*

**2**. §6.3.2.1/1: ***An lvalue is an expression*** (with an object type other than void) **that potentially designates an object**;<sup>64)</sup> if an lvalue does not designate an object when it is evaluated, the behavior is undefined. When an object is said to have a particular type, the type is specified by the lvalue used to designate the object. **A modifiable lvalue is an lvalue that does not have array type, does not have an incomplete type, does not have a const- qualified type, and if it is a structure or union, does not have any member (including, recursively, any member or element of all contained aggregates or unions) with a const- qualified type**.</sub>

Comment: May you please explain your line:-"The left operand of = operator must be an lvalue (modifiable)."

Comment: @sam; Added some details about "lvalue" and `"modifiable lvalue".

Answer (score 0):

- Just replace your:

  ```
  a > b ? g = a : g = b ;
  ```

  with

  ```
  a > b ? (g = a) : (g = b) ;
  ```
- Because precedance of Parentheses is higher.So if condition `a > b` is become true then value of a is assigned to g and if it fails then value of b is assigned to g.